# Github one topic per issue, where is this documented?

Tags: github

I posted a new issue on github for an opensource project. Shortly after posting I got a comment on the new issue saying "ya I agree and also [XYZ subject tangentially related to your ABC issue] needs to be fixed also".

On Stackexchange websites there is clear documentation specifying one topic per question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts (maybe there is a better link but this is the link I found).

**Where on github.com can I find something similarly authoritative to point a user to that says "it is recommended to post one topic per Github-issue"?**

Comment: It is considered good practice to discuss one item per issue, but that would come under "how to use a bug tracker", not "how to use GitHub".

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, and it doesn't make sense for GitHub.

Every person who owns a repo on GitHub can decide for himself how he manages the issues in his repo. Usually, you find such information somewhere in the repo. Sometimes a repo has a `CONTRIBUTING.md` file that details this. If it has, then it is linked when you try to open an issue. If it hasn't, look for this info in `README` files or in the wiki or the projects homepage.

But sometimes, you will not find it. And by that time, you start using common sense. *Usually*, the rule is to only discuss one issue per opened issue because that makes sense from a software development point of view. Its the only way you can label things properly, mark then done as properly, assign them to a person properly. And most importantly, it means that all info related to one issue is found at one place, making it easy to find at one glance.

Thus, virtually every contribution guidelines will state something in that direction, and when you can not find those explicitly, the general consensus and the expectancy is what I just laid out above.